# Firefox Webextension works only on my PC

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions, error-logging

I hope sombody can help me. 
I have a really simple webextension with a conentenscript and one backgroundscript (contains some javascript, close tabs and open tabs with specific url). This webextension works fine on my computer but fail on customers and I dont know why because I have the exact same Firefox version (58.0, 32bit), copy & paste the exact same prefs.js in my profile folder and open the exact same url.

So my plan is to log every step in my code to find out how far its going well till it breaks but how can I write my logs to a file in webextension. Just tried the console.log but the logs are gone when my webextension close the tab.

Maybe there are some permission issues or something like that. My webextension is signed and require two permission (access data from all websites and access all tabs).

Comment: Try the debugger.  https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/11/go-beyond-console-log-with-the-firefox-debugger/

Comment: Im already using the debugger but I cant debug on customers computer. Like i said, its works fine on my computer.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood you. Can you write to storage or post to a server instead?  Alternately if you can post your code maybe someone could spot an issue.